# Sequence in $L^p([0,1])$ with no convergent subsequence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

The question I am asked is:

Find a bound sequence in $l^p$, $L^p([0,1])$ and $C([0,1])$ respectively, which has no convergent subsequence.

I guess I have found such sequences in $l^p$ (namely $(x_n)_n$ with $\xi_{n,k}=1$ if $n=k$ and $\xi_{n,k}=0$ if $n\ne k$) and $C([0,1])$ ($x_n(t)=t^n$) but I am not able to find such a sequence for $L^p([0,1])$. Since there is no measure given, I am assuming I should prove it for the Lebesgue-measure. If it were the counting measure, for example, it would be easy.

If I want to find such a sequence with the Lebesgue-measure I can not let the norm of the functions of my sequence diverge to infinity. I also can not find a good way of dividing my interval $[0,1]$ into (countably) infinite subintervals which all do not have measure $0$ and do not converge.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Look at $f_n=n^{1/p}\chi_{[0,1/n]}$. You have that $|f|=1$.

Answer (score 2):

arts gave a suitable counter-example for $\mathbb L^p$: let $f_n$ be the function defined on $[0,1]$ by 
\begin{equation}
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
n^{1/p}&\mbox{if }0\leqslant x\leqslant 1/n,\\
0&\mbox{if }1/n\lt  x\leqslant 1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then the $\mathbb L^p$-norm of $f_n$ is $1$. The sequence $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges almost everywhere to $0$. If a subsequence converged in $\mathbb L^p$ to some $f$, then we would be able to extract a further subsequence which converges almost everywhere to $f$ hence $f=0$ and $\left\lVert f_n\right\rVert_p\to 0$, a contradiction.